# React Lifting State in Component with Containment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I currently have a modal system with containment. There is a ModalWrapper that handles closing the modal and form submission. The actual modal content goes in another component, which I called EventsModalForm:

Modal Wrapper:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { EVENT_FORM_MODAL } from '../layout/modalTypes';

const ModalWrapper = props => {
  const handleBackgroundClick = e => {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) props.hideModal();
  };

  const onOk = () => {
    if (props.modal.currentModal === EVENT_FORM_MODAL){
      //Do form submition 
    } else {
      props.onOk();
    }
    props.hideModal();
  };

  const [formStates, setFormStates] = useState({
    ...props.modal.form_fields
  });
  const handleFormChange = e => {
    return setFormStates({ ...formStates, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] })    
  }


  const okButton = props.showOk
    ? (
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={onOk}
        disabled={props.okDisabled}
      >
        {props.modal.okText}
      </button>
    ) : null;


  return (
    <div className="modal-overlay-div" onClick={handleBackgroundClick}>
      <div style={modal_content_div}>
        <header>
            <span>
              <button onClick={props.hideModal} className="close">&times;</button>
            </span>
            <h1>{props.title}</h1>  
          <hr />   
        </header>

        {props.children}

        {okButton}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
//content shortened for clarity  

export default ModalWrapper;
```

EventsModalForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Label
} from "reactstrap";

import 'flatpickr/dist/themes/material_blue.css';
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr';


import ModalWrapper from './ModalWrapper';

const EventsFormModal = props => {
  //have form hook here
  return (
    <ModalWrapper
      {...props}
      title="Event form"
      width={600}
      showOk={true}
    >
      <Form>
        //form...
      </Form>
    </ModalWrapper>
  );
};

export default EventsFormModal;
```

I'm trying to use hooks within the EventsFormModal, and whenever onOk gets called, have state be passed to ModalWrapper. However, with the way my modal is set up, I can't seem to find a way to lift state to ModalWrapper. Props passed to ModalWrapper and EventsFormModal are the same, so I wouldn't be able to create a function in the parent component and pass it as props to the child. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're just trying to run a function when ```onOk``` is called? I'm not clear on why you wouldn't be able to pass in a callback as a prop, or simply add new state inside ```EvensFormModal```. I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to get user inputs in the form, which I store in a hook. The data has to be passed to the parent ModalWrapper in order for it to call a function and pass the correct parameters.I would have to pass an onChange function only to EventsFormModal, but it would also be passed to ModalWrapper with the way the modal is set up.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. This may not be the most helpful, but to me it would make more sense for the form to be a component which handles its own submission, and itself triggers any actions that need to occur in the modal (closing, etc.), which can be easily passed down as props, rather than trying to lift the state up, though it's certainly possible.

Comment: So you want the EventsFormModal state passed to the ModalWrapper after someone clicks OK in the modal?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to pass the data that was entered back to `ModalWrapper` once the user clicks 'OK'.. I made this little demo to show how you can do something like this..

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const SomeModal = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const showModal = () => setShow(true);
  const hideModal = () => setShow(false);
  
  const handleNameChange = event => setName(event.target.value);
  const handleEmailChange = event => setEmail(event.target.value);

  return (
    <main>
      <ModalWrapper show={show} handleClose={hideModal} onOk={({name, email})}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleNameChange} placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="text" onChange={handleEmailChange} placeholder="Email" />
      </ModalWrapper>
      <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};

const ModalWrapper = ({ handleClose, show, children, onOk }) => {
  const [onOkData, setOnOkData] = useState();
  const showHideClassName = show ? "modal display-block" : "modal display-none";
  
  const handleModalClose = (event, data) => {
    handleClose();
    setOnOkData(onOk);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
      <section className="modal-main">
        {children}
        <button onClick={handleModalClose}>Ok</button>
      </section>
    </div>
      {onOkData 
        ? <pre>This data was sent from "SomeModal": {JSON.stringify(onOkData, null, 2)}</pre> 
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => <SomeModal />

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.modal-main {
  position:fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```